# Serverless: Using a private Python package as a dependency

Tags: python, pip, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a Python Serverless project that uses a private Git (on Github) repo.

Requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
itsdangerous==0.24
boto3>=1.7
git+ssh://git@github.com/company/repo.git#egg=my_alias
```

Configurations of the project mainly looks like this

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    dockerSsh: true
```

When I deploy using this command:

```
sls deploy --aws-profile my_id --stage dev --region eu-west-1
```

I get this error:

```
  Command "git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/company/repo.git /tmp/pip-install-a0_8bh5a/my_alias" failed with error code 128 in None
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm suspecting either the way I configured my SSH key for Github access or the configurations of the serverless package.

Comment: 1. When cloning from Github with the ssh url, you have to provide the ssh key, so if you need ssh clone, you have to put the private key into container and setup the ssh agent. 2. What is ssh clone necessary for in the container anyway? You're just installing the package without planning to change the upstream code etc, so replace the requirements url with `https://github.com/company/repo.git#egg=my_alias` and ready.

Comment: @hoefling, that is what `dockerSsh: true`, it maps the keys from outside to inside the container. `M-T-A`, can you add `--verbose` flag to your deploy command and share the output of the same

Comment: What version of `serverless-python-requirements` do you use?

Comment: also, do you run `sls deploy` in interactive shell or via some build system? If you run it in console, you can authenticate interactively using git+https://

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the only way I managed to sort this issue was

1. Configure the SSH WITH NO PASSPHRASE. Following steps [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).
2. In `serverless.yml`, I added the following:

```
    custom:
      wsgi:
        app: app.app
        packRequirements: false
      pythonRequirements:
        dockerizePip: true
        dockerSsh: true
        dockerSshSymlink: ~/.ssh
```

Notice I added `dockerSshSymlink` to report the location of the ssh files on my local machine; `~/.ssh`.

3. In `requirements.txt`, I added my private dependency like this:

   `git+ssh://git@github.com/my_comp/my_repo.git#egg=MyRepo`

All works.

Comment: I tried the same, but still get the ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128.
What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Although not recommeneded. Have you tried using `sudo sls deploy --aws-profile my_id --stage dev --region eu-west-1`

This error can be also created by using the wrong password or ssh key.